# Check if a remote desktop connection is active in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, command-line, remote-desktop

As part of a business solution we are offering several remote desktops to a user base.  Currently the users must go system by system attempting to connect and find one that is not already being used.  I'd like to see if there is a command that can be run to quickly query an IP and see if there is an active remote connection already.

I've run across a 'wmic' solution already, but this only seems to work if the person running the command has admin access on the destination machine.  I don't need a username returned or any information other than if there is a currently in-use remote connection.

Any idea's?

Researched solutions that didn't pan out listed below:

wmic /node:*IP* ComputerSystem GET UserName     ---Returns only if requestor is an admin

qwinsta /server:*IP*                            ---RPC is not enabled on all machienes

eventvwr *IP*                                   ---Too technical and time consuming for end users

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any reason RPC can't be enabled on the machines? That's the most direct route to get the info you're looking for.

Comment: Unfortunatly not.  Due to company policies, RPC can't be enabled.  The work around we use, which seems like a bigger security risk than just enabling RPC to me, was to create logon and logoff VB scripts that write the USERNAME environmental variable to a sharepoint list.

Answer (score 1):

query session /SERVER:servername